# ReactJS Split screen in two halves

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

How can I split the screen in two halves such as: [image] in order for in each half to add my custom elements?

Example: the blue side is a picture, the second half contains some random text inputs

I've been trying like this:

```
<div className={styles.splitScreen}>
        <div className={styles.topPane}>
          {topPane}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.bottomPane}>
          {bottomPane}
        </div>
      </div>
```

with a scss file containing:

```
.splitScreen {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;

  .topPane,
  .bottomPane {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }

  .topPane {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

but to no success.

Comment: Are they supposed to be side by side or one on top of the other?

Comment: @ellitt side by side

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a good use case for CSS flexbox. [CSS FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<div className={styles.splitScreen}>
  <div className={styles.topPane}>{topPane}</div>
  <div className={styles.bottomPane}>{bottomPane}</div>
</div>
```

styles object:

```
splitScreen: {
    display: 'flex';
    flexDirection: 'row';
},
topPane: {
    width: '50%',
},
bottomPane: {
    width: '50%',
},
```

EDIT: If they should be side-by-side, use `flexDirection: 'row',`.

Comment: If they're supposed to be next to each other, you'll want to make the `flex-direction: row;` or leave it out entirely since that's the default.

Comment: thank you @iepuf1lla, is there however a way to make an image in the first div to fit the entire height of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want flexbox or css-grid.

Since there's already an answer for flexbox from iepur1lla, here's a css-grid alternative;

```
.splitScreen {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

And if you want to be sure that topPane and bottomPane are always in these two positions, you can add this to the CSS:

```
  .topPane {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  .bottomPane {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
```